# Reducing the voltage of a PWM signal

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, voltage-divider

I will be needing a 1.25V PWM input into an LED driver (AP8802) and will have to interface it with a 5v PWM output from a micro-controller (ATMEGA328). Would a simple potential divider do the job, or is there a better option?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just halve the duty cycle?

Comment: The voltage divider should work (I assume we are talking about the CTRL input, right?)

Comment: Yes, the LED driver is dependant on voltage so at 1.25v the output of the LED will be driven at 100% (set by a resistor) but if it goes higher, it will be driven at a much higher current.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the datasheet is clear about it: *A Pulse Width Modulated (PWM) signal with duty cycle DPWM can be applied to the CTRL pin to adjust the output current to a value above or
below the nominal average value set by resistor RSET. When driving the CTRL with a voltage waveform care should be taken not to exceed a
drive voltage of 2.5V (where extra brightness is required) or 1.25V if a maximum of 100% brightness is required.*

Comment: Yes I do mean the CTRL input, thank you for your time Eugene!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to think of would be the resistive divider you suggest.

To get a good dynamic output you need to not make the resistors too large, since the internal schematic shows a 50k resistor from the reference, so using 110k and 330k would mean you cannot pull the CTRL pin close enough to 0V to really consider it PWM-ing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feuzwK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I added a Zener diode there to hard-clip any erroneous signal glitches to something near 1.4V, so that you won't instantly melt your devices if something happens you didn't foresee.

You want 1.25V, which is exactly 1/4th of 5V, so if the total resistance is R, then Rd (for R-pull-down) needs to be 1/4th of R in the divider, so that 1/4th of the source signal falls across it.

So Ru (for R-pull-up) needs to be the rest, or 3/4th of R.

Which means Ru = 3*Rd.

So 1.1k and 3.3k would work.

---

But funny thing:

Did you notice me mentioning that resistor earlier?

That pulls the CTRL pin to 1.25V all by itself, no worries. So why not try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX6tup.png)</sup>

Whenever your PWM signal is high, the transistor is on, pulls the CTRL low to 0V. Whenever it it low, it lets the pin go, and the internal resistor will pull it up to 1.25V.

You may see a small RC-curve bump at the peak current, created by the 50k resistor and trace and transistor capacitance, but it should be very small (possibly even unnoticeable) in almost all normal use cases.

Of course, that will invert your PWM effect, but in an MCU (at least the Atmels I know from experience) that's very easy to flip.

Comment: Wow, I would have never even thought of doing it the second way! Thank You!

Comment: @NikitaK Turns out it's always worth while to look at the datasheet carefully ;-)